# Session details lost after downloading Word document from load balanced servers

Tags: xml, coldfusion, internet-explorer-8, http-headers, iis-7.5

We have recently migrated a web application to a load balanced pair of servers. The document is built dynamically from the database using XML formatting and downloaded with the `application/msword` MIME type. This works in Chrome, but in IE8 and possibly other IE versions, the document is downloaded but when clicking a link on the page, the user is redirected to the login screen.

On examination of the HTTP headers using Fiddler, it seems that the server issues the 405 HTTP status code (Method not Allowed) and the load balancer switches to the alternate server which does not hold the user's session details, hence logging them out. Why is the 405 status code issued only for IE browsers and why should it cause the load balancer to switch servers?

The server is IIS 7.5 with ColdFusion 9.

This is the HTTP header information written before the response data.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value='inline; filename="#CreateUUID()#.doc"'>
<cfcontent type='application/msword'>
```

Has anyone else experienced this with a similar server setup (not necessarily ColdFusion or IIS)? Although Chrome is a workaround, our users may not have sufficient access to install non-IE browsers.

Comment: Some questions that may help to clarify the issue. In your Fiddler output, what is being requested that generated the 405 status code? What method is being used for that request? Is the link that is causing the 405 status code contained within the Word document? If not, then how are the users getting from the just downloaded Word document to the link that causes the 405? Is your load balancing configured to use "sticky" sessions?

Comment: The load balancer is using "sticky" sessions.  Users are clicking on a standard HTML link on the web page to a Coldfusion script which generates the XML which is then pushed back to the client with a Word MIME type. Word is only the helper application called by the browser.

Comment: Okay so the document is successfully downloaded and opened in Word. Right? Then the user clicks on some other link back in the IE browser? I think the 405 status code is a red herring here. I have seen Word make HTTP requests back to the server to see what options are supported. Check the User Agent of those 405 calls in your IIS logs. They are probably from "Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery" (or something similar). So I think the real question is why your load balancer is not keeping the stickyness for subsequent requests? Again I ask for you to share your Fiddler output or re-examine it.

Comment: Two requests were being made to the same script on the server,  because IE prompts the user with the File Download popup.  After accepting to open the document, a separate request was made with different session tokens causing the load balancer to swap servers in some instances.   I seem to resolved it now by changing the Content-Disposition header from inline; to attachment;.

Comment: Just to add that the requests are not from "Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery", which are usually caused by links from Word documents. I have seen these and they go to the 500 error handler which is handled by the load balancer.

Comment: Cool, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Microsoft Office MIME Types in IIS but use "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" instead. This supersedes the "application/msword" mimetype

Below is the complete list of office mimetypes:

http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php

Here are the steps in adding the mimetype in IIS:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for this advice.  Both mimetypes are set up in IIS, the new xml one for .docx and the original for .doc.

Comment: I also tried changing the mimetype of the dynamically generated document, but Word would not open it - it said the format was corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to resolved this problem by amending the Content-Disposition header from inline to attachment, so that the whole download is handled in one request and one session.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value='attachment; filename="#CreateUUID()#.doc"'>
```